# file path structures ajax and php sessions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, session

I am working on a projects that is kind of all over the place. My display file is index.php. From there I make calls via jquery to ajax functions which then call php file that gets and receives user data from mysql table. The php functions saves some data into php session variables, sometimes just returns data back to ajax.

I am fairly new to ajax, php and mostly sessions and am finding i may be having trouble with the way I am making my file paths......For exaple, I have found that sometimes using the full URL file path rather than just /functions/updateUser.php can break the link!

So my question is, how exactly does the server pass variables through php sessions?

If my file structures are the following, can this create issues? My second question would be can file structure also affect how ajax data is returned?

Root > index.php
Root > sessions.php
Root > functions > (php files that make calls to database)
Root > scripts > (js files that make calls to the php functions)

I have searched for tutorials that can help give me a more clear understanding (and mental picture) of how this information is passed from page to page, but have found nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just tackle an interesting problem and you'll have to do it right.

To answer to your questions:

1) $_SESSION is used to build persistent behaviour in your apps, which means you can pass data across your requests. **Everything that can be serialized**, it is serialized as string and written in a file. When requested, data is unserialized from that file and rebuilded into $_SESSION array. [More about the sessions here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

2) No, as long as you return a valid string (from your PHP scripts) with proper Content-Type, etc. The "ajax data" is simply echoed string from your PHP script(s). Set the headers properly ex: `header('Content-Type: text/javascript');` before echoing.

**A note about the content type**: it depends what do you want to achieve at the other side. If you are using jQuery and build your client side logic with it, probably you want to send JSON. In this case I would recommend to set your content type to "text/javascript" instead of "proper" type which is "application/json". I used to have a lot of problems with Internet Exploder and Firefox, where browsers were confused with application/json.
It always works as expected with "text/javascript" which is fine since JSON is javascript (notation).

There is a nice ini directive "`include_path`" that you can tweak for your specific needs. The useful functions are [set_include_path()](http://php.net/set_include_path) and [get_include_path()](http://php.net/get_include_path). You can make wonders with only these two.

Files in PHP are included by the order in "include_path" directive.
To make it more flexible while including/requiring files, consider 3 most used practices:

1. set your include_path with your file structure
2. build some fancy autoloader (see [spl_autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) feature)
3. 5.3+ only, use namespaces

These days `include_path` is not so popular since everyone tends to blow things with "proper ways" and other lame excuses. In case you don't build another Facebook, Twitter or Youtube-wannabe app, consider include_path. It's simple, and can be very powerful (instead of using bloated techniques).

Plan your structure, and add your directories like this:

```
<?php
// somewhere at the very top of your entry script
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array_merge(array(
    '/path/to/app/dir1',
    '/path/to/app/dir2',
    '/even/path/outside/your/app',
    // ...
), explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATH))));
?>
```

This will combine the current paths set in your php.ini file (DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATH) with yours.

Now when you include/require some script it will try to include it by the order of this list.

Sorry for the long explanation. Hope it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure is fine and it has nothing to do with any coding issue.

When making an AJAX call, you are calling an URL and hence complete URLs are fine. However, when calling your functions you are actually including a file which is expected to reside in your server folder and hence the calls need to be relative to the location of your calling file and not URLs.

**Session**

When you call session_start() it generates a cookie and stores the session ID in the client browser. Hence, any client browser that is configured to reject cookies will not be able to use sessions. When you set a session variable, the server stores it in the session ID file in the session file on the server. When your program requests a value from session then PHP checks for that variable in that session file and returns that value. The idea is large data kept on session files makes the server slow and is not the ideal way to code. In your programs you can check out jQuery and how a few lines of code in jQuery can lift your program to utilize AJAX with JSON to send and receive quite large amounts of data very efficiently.

More information on PHP Session is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

jQuery AJAX information is [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).